# Unrecognisable Name error in bigquery I do not understand why

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

This is my code

```
SELECT
 `First_dataset.employees.name` AS name,
 `First_dataset.employees.role` AS role
FROM
 `First_dataset.employees`
```

Its keeps telling me unrecognisable name

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj5NC.png)

Does anyone know what i can do

Comment: Does this work? 
`SELECT name, role FROM First_dataset.employees`